# Calling asmx web service using jQuery

Tags: jquery, web-services, asmx

I'm trying to call a .NET asmx web service using jQuery. I've been using guides [here](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=5872924) and [here](http://www.tomot.de/en-us/article/8/asp.net/how-to-use-jquery-to-call-a-webservice-asmx-method) and as far as I can tell I've followed them to the letter.

Service Code:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/", Description = "...")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[ScriptService]
public class MyService : WebService
{

    private static readonly IKernel NinjectKernel = new StandardKernel(new IocModule());

    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld(string name)
    {
        return string.Format("Hello {0}", name);
    }
```

I can happily browse to the service in Firefox and invoke the HelloWorld method.

Client jQuery:

```
    if (ajaxRunning) {
        return;
    }
    ajaxRunning = true;

    var webMethod = "http://localhost:51546/MyService.asmx/HelloWorld";
    var inputname = "Jack";

    $("[id$='spinner']").show();
    $("[id$='spinnerText']").show();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: webMethod,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {name: inputname},
        success: function (msg) {
            $("[id$='spinner']").hide();
            $("[id$='spinnerText']").hide();
            ajaxRunning = false;
            alert(msg.d);
        },
        error: function() {
            $("[id$='spinner']").hide();
            $("[id$='spinnerText']").hide();
            ajaxRunning = false;
            alert("Fail");
        }
    });
```

When I run the javascript there are no errors in Firebug, just the Fail alert pop-up. Please tell me if I am doing something obviously wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Need to stringify the parameters being sent to the WebService.
The:

```
data: {name: inputname}
```

Need to be replaced with:

```
data: JSON.stringify({name: inputname})
```